# Test param value using EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I'm attempting to write some unit tests using EasyMock and TestNG and have run into a question.  Given the following:

```
void execute(Foo f) {
  Bar b = new Bar()
  b.setId(123);
  f.setBar(b);
}
```

I'm trying to test that the Id of the Bar gets set accordingly in the following fashion:

```
@Test
void test_execute() {
  Foo f = EasyMock.createMock(Foo.class);

  execute(f);

  Bar b = ?; // not sure what to do here
  f.setBar(b);
  f.expectLastCall();
}
```

In my test, I can't just call `f.getBar()` and inspect it's Id because `f` is a mock object.  Any thoughts?  Is this where I'd want to look at the EasyMock v2.5 additions `andDelegateTo()` and `andStubDelegateTo()`?

Oh, and just for the record... EasyMock's documentation blows.

Comment: I believe if you create the very same bar, it would work. Why don't you try?

Comment: It's my understanding that this approach would rely on the implementation of Bar.equals() more so than the implementation of my execute() method.  While I think this would work, it seems like there's a better way.

Comment: yes, you would be asserting that the bar instance passed to the mock is equal to the one you expect. If your the `equals()` method of Bar is not enough to satisfy what you want to test, or tests more fields than you care about in your test, then capture is a better option (although it raises the question of what Bar.equals() isn't sufficient).

Comment: agreed, but testing Bar.equals() isn't the job of the test I'm currently working on ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah ha!  Capture is the key.

```
@Test
void test_execute() {
  Foo f = EasyMock.createMock(Foo.class);

  Capture<Bar> capture = new Capture<Bar>();
  f.setBar(EasyMock.and(EasyMock.isA(Bar.class), EasyMock.capture(capture)));
  execute(f);

  Bar b = capture.getValue();  // same instance as that set inside execute()
  Assert.assertEquals(b.getId(), ???);
}
```

Comment: For a more detailed explanation, checkout my EasyMock tutorial (specifically part 3): https://turnlevel.com/2013/05/28/easymock-fundamentals-3/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?`

```
final Bar bar = new Bar(); 
bar.setId(123);
EasyMock.expect(f.getBar()).andAnswer(new IAnswer<Bar>() {
     public Bar answer() {             
         return bar;
     }
});
```

I am not sure of the syntax on top of my head but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
f.setBar(EasyMock.isA(Bar.class))
```

This will ensure setBar was called with a Bar class as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd construct an Object which is `equal` to the one I expect to get back. In this case, I'd create a `new Bar` and set it's ID to 123, relying on the correct implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()` of `Bar` and the default behavior of EasyMocks argument matcher (using equal comparison for parameters).

```
@Test
public void test_execute() {
    Foo f = EasyMock.createMock(Foo.class);
    Bar expected = new Bar();
    expected.setId(123);
    f.setBar(expected);
    EasyMock.expectLastCall();
    EasyMock.replay(f);

    execute(f);

    EasyMock.verify(f);
}
```

Comment: I would argue this is more a test of the implementation of Bar than the method you're intending to test.